# memsql-ops start error in thread-7

Tags: singlestore

After installing and starting memsql-ops, it shows the following error:

```
# ./memsql-ops start 
Starting MemSQL Ops...
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 869, in run
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/daemon/manage.py", line 200, in startup_watcher
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/network/api_client.py", line 34, in call
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Does anyone know the issue?

- OS : CentOS 6.7
- Memsql : 5.1.0 Enterprise Trial

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have another server running on the port Ops is trying to start with (default 9000) that is returning data which is not JSON decodable.  The solution is to either start MemSQL Ops on a different port, or kill the server running at that port.

We will fix this bug in an upcoming release of Ops!  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Even starting memsql-ops on different port, same error occurs;

Comment: When it is installed in vm machine, it works fine. I guess it seems that it might need internet connection in order to install it.

Comment: The error that you hit is raised during our startup while we are waiting for the new agent process to start up and bind on it's port.  During the startup process a thread tries connecting to the new process in a loop.  Ops does not require internet access to start since it does not reach out to the internet at any point during the startup process.

If you want more assistance please join us in our public slack channel here: http://chat.memsql.com